# What class of problem would one use a binary search tree to solve?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search

I've seen this data structure talked about a lot, but I am unclear as to what sort of problem would demand such a data structure (over alternative representations). I've never needed one, but perhaps that's because I don't quite grok it. *Can you enlighten me?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example of where you would use a binary search tree would be a sorted list of values where you want to be able to quickly add elements.

Consider using an array for this purpose.  You have very fast access to read random values, but if you want to add a new value, you have to find the place in the array where it belongs, shift everything over, and then insert the new value.

With a binary search tree, you simply traverse the tree looking for where the value would be if it were in the tree already, and then add it there.

Also, consider if you want to find out if your sorted array contains a particular value.  You have to start at one end of the array and compare the value you're looking for to each individual value until you either find the value in the array, or pass the point where it would have been.  With a binary search tree, you greatly reduce the number of comparisons you are likely to have to make.  Just a quick caveat, however, it is definitely possible to contrive situations where the binary search tree requires more comparisons, but these are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the kind of answer I was looking for. Now I understand exactly when to use one. I am enlightened.

Answer (score 5):

One thing I've used it for in the past is Huffman decoding (or any variable-bit-length scheme).

If you maintain your binary tree with the characters at the leaves, each incoming bit decides whether you move to the left or right node.

When you reach a leaf node, you have your decoded character and you can start on the next one.

For example, consider the following tree:

```
    .
   / \
  .   C
 / \
A   B
```

This would be a tree for a file where the predominant letter was `C` (by having less bits used for common letters, the file is shorter than it would be for a fixed-bit-length scheme). The codes for the individual letters are:

```
A: 00 (left, left).
B: 01 (left, right).
C: 1  (right).
```

The *class* of problems you use then for are those where you want to be able to both insert and access elements reasonably efficiently. As well as unbalanced trees (such as the Huffman example above), you can also use *balanced* trees which make the insertions a little more costly (since you may have to rebalance on the fly) but make lookups a lot more efficient since you're traversing the minimum possible number of nodes.

Comment: I saw this question and was about to say "Huffman Decoding!" but you beat me to it. This is a classic example and perfect-fit application, which tops it all off with a references coding theory.

Comment: +1 for explaining huffman decoding which I always considered something of a dark art. :)

Comment: How much do you know about video compression?

Answer (score 2):

from wiki

Self-balancing binary search trees can be used in a natural way to construct and maintain ordered lists, such as priority queues. They can also be used for associative arrays; key-value pairs are simply inserted with an ordering based on the key alone. In this capacity, self-balancing BSTs have a number of advantages and disadvantages over their main competitor, hash tables. One advantage of self-balancing BSTs is that they allow fast (indeed, asymptotically optimal) enumeration of the items in key order, which hash tables do not provide. One disadvantage is that their lookup algorithms get more complicated when there may be multiple items with the same key.

Self-balancing BSTs can be used to implement any algorithm that requires mutable ordered lists, to achieve optimal worst-case asymptotic performance. For example, if binary tree sort is implemented with a self-balanced BST, we have a very simple-to-describe yet asymptotically optimal O(n log n) sorting algorithm. Similarly, many algorithms in computational geometry exploit variations on self-balancing BSTs to solve problems such as the line segment intersection problem and the point location problem efficiently. (For average-case performance, however, self-balanced BSTs may be less efficient than other solutions. Binary tree sort, in particular, is likely to be slower than mergesort or quicksort, because of the tree-balancing overhead as well as cache access patterns.)

Self-balancing BSTs are flexible data structures, in that it's easy to extend them to efficiently record additional information or perform new operations. For example, one can record the number of nodes in each subtree having a certain property, allowing one to count the number of nodes in a certain key range with that property in O(log n) time. These extensions can be used, for example, to optimize database queries or other list-processing algorithms.